# I want to show data which got from a php file to all tab pages by using ‘storage event’

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want that when I click on logout, `ck()` function will be fired and there is an ajax method. By ajax method I have send some data to `object.php` file. After success all process I will get `I got It` string. Now I want that when this data I will get, `'storage'` event will execute and `I got It` will show all `index.php` tab pages at a times without any refresh or click again logout. I am very very sorry for my poor English. It is my first question.

**index.php:**

```
<script>
function ck(){
    var ok="thx";
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        data:{mt:ok},
        url:"object.php",
        success:function(html){
            if(html!=""){
                localStorage.setItem('store-it', html);
                window.addEventListener('storage', function (event){
                    if(event.key=='store-it'){
                        $(".show").text(event.newValue);
                    }
                })
            }
        },
    });
}
</script>
<p onclick="ck()">logout</p>
<p class="show"></p>
```

**object.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['mt']) && $_GET['mt']=="thx"){
    echo "I got It";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks dear Rasclatt

Comment: Why not just use a php `$_SESSION` for this? You can set it using ajax and it will be available on all other pages when you navigate to them, provided they have `session_start();` at the top of the page.

Comment: but in this case page will need refresh. pls see the below code..<p><label for="data"></label> <input type="text" name="data" id="data" />
<p id="fromEvent"><code>storage</code></p><script>

var dataInput = document.getElementById('data'),
    output = document.getElementById('fromEvent');

dataInput.addEventListener('keyup', function (){
     localStorage.setItem('storage-event-test', this.value);
})

window.addEventListener('storage', function (event){
    alert(event);
    if (event.key == 'storage-event-test') {
    output.innerHTML = event.newValue;
  }
})

</script>

Comment: You populate this current page with the return but only after you have saved it to the session. Subsequent pages would be populated by the session.